# Identification from minimum value of truncated distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, descriptive-statistics, estimators, identifiability

Suppose that a given population is endowed with a pair of characteristics $T$ and $K$. Let's think of these characteristics as random variables   $$(T,K) \sim \operatorname{BiNormal}((\mu_T, \mu_K), (\sigma_T,\sigma_K), \rho)$$

Suppose now that I observe the realisations of $T$ for a sample consisting of those individuals with $K<a$, where the selection threshold $a$ is unknown.

I have a theoretical model that predicts the value of $a$ for any set of the underlying parameters $(\mu_T, \mu_K)$ and $ (\sigma_T,\sigma_K), \rho$.

Assuming I know all the parameters but one (say, $\rho$), I could use the theoretical model to predict $a$ (say $\hat{a}$), and then estimate  $\rho$ using minimum distance (i.e. find the value of $\rho$ that minimises difference between $E[T|K<\hat{a}]$ and the observed mean of the selected sample).

Now assume that I know all the parameters but **two** (say $\rho$ and $\sigma_T$). I could similarly estimate $\rho$ and $\sigma_T$ by simultaneously minimising the distance for $Var[T|K<\hat{a}]$ and $E[T|K<\hat{a}]$.

Now I've run out of usual suspects to target... Is it possible to identify another unknown parameter (say $\sigma_K$), for example, from the observed minimum value of $T$ in the selected sample?

Comment: *What* a statistic estimates is for you to stipulate; it makes no sense to ask about it.  (That would be neither a meaningful statistical nor a mathematical question.)  What would make sense as a question would be something like "what properties does $\underline{T}$ have as an estimator of such-and-such?"  Conceivably you could inquire about theoretical properties of $\underline{T}$, such as its moments, its distribution, or whatever: but if that's your interest, it would help to edit the post to make that intent plain.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for this. I agree the current wording is sloppy–obviously any statistic can be an estimator of anything, and the relevant question is whether $\underline{T}$ is a 'good' estimator of something specifically. Perhaps I should rather ask: does $\underline{T}$ contain information that is not already contained in the truncated sample mean and variance? and if so, is there a way of obtaining an expression of this information in terms of the parameters pinning down the population distribution

Comment: I'm bothered by a few things that could use your clarification.  One is that the expectation of $\underline{T}$ depends on the sample size.  Another is that this expectation diverges (to $-\infty$) as the sample size grows.  This gives me the impression that the post might not be asking the right question: it offers us a statistic for examination but it doesn't really help us understand what the underlying *statistical* question or motivation might be.  What are you actually trying to learn about $T$ and $K$?

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. I think you are right – I tried to abstract the question from a larger problem. So I'll re-write it in a second to see if that helps. If you think it's too different, I can delete this post and open a new one.

Comment: The new wording hopefully makes clear that this is ultimately a question of identification under 'structural estimation'. I've added the 'identification' tag, but would of course be happy to delete the question and post it again if that seems better practice.

Comment: Are you looking for something besides an expression for the pdf of a truncated bivariate normal distribution, and moments thereof?

Comment: I want to know how many parameters from the joint normal distribution can be identified from observing the truncated distribution (with truncation as per the explanation in the OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to a Type II Tobit, or [Heckit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/vignettes/selection.pdf) model.

In such models, we posit latent variables
$$
(T, K) \sim \mbox{BiNormal}(\mu, \Sigma)
$$
and observe
$$
Y = \begin{cases}
T, K>a \\
0, K \leq a
\end{cases}
$$

You have it *at least as difficult* as the Heckit model (since you don't even get to know that $K$ was below a threshold).  In fact, you have only the second term of the likelihood in equation 11 of the linked reference
$$
P(T=t|K>a) = \frac{1}{\sigma_T} \phi \bigl( (t-\mu_T)/\sigma_T \bigr) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \Phi \left(\frac{a-\mu_K - \rho\sigma_T/\sigma_K(t-\mu_T) }{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \right),
$$
where $\phi(z)$ and $\Phi(z)$ are the standard normal pdf and cdf, respectively, evaluated at $z$.
(You can show this by writing $P(T,K>a)=P(K>a|T) P(T)$ and observing that $P(K|T)$ is Normal.)

### Identifiability

I can easily see the following (which are true in the Heckit model as well)

1. Only $\mu_K-a$ is estimible.
2. $\sigma_K$ and $a-\mu_K$ are not simultaneously identifiable.

In general, it's not simple to show that identifiability holds, since it boils down to finding the roots of $P_\theta(t|K>a) - P_{\theta'}(t|K>a') = 0$, which is a transcendental equation!

Showing that identifiability fails to hold is easier.  If the variance-covariance matrix of the MLE is singular then you have a recipe for generating new $\theta$ that will return the same likelihood, so you have good evidence that your model is singular.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. I actually have a model that endogenously determines $a$; so I intend to use GMM. What I want to know here is what information is contained in $\underline{T}$, so that I can then use it as a target moment... It seems to me that simply using sample averages and variances as target moments does not exploit all the information I have from observing the truncated distribution.

Comment: In general, it seems like the answer is that $\underline{T}$ may contain no information (except on $\mu_T$ and $\sigma_T$).  Also, you'd need to take the expectation w/r/t a finite sample for $E(\underline{T)}$ to converge to anything anyways.  I am unfamiliar with the theory of finite-sample MOM estimators...

Comment: Thanks for this – much clearer. I've accepted the answer and will delete my previous comment (referring to the initial answer, before I updated the question)